# Creating a loop that deletes specific values from a row in DFs into a list

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of 6936 elements, and I want to delete all the rows that have as flow value -1 in all the data frames in the list.

I made an example of how my data frame looks like inside the list

```r
x <- data.frame(
  date = c(1, 2, 3),
  month = c(1, 1, 1),
  year = c(2000, 2000, 2000),
  flow = c(32.2, -1, 23.22)
)
```

Basically I want to write a loop that does this:

```r
df <- list[[1]]       

a <- df[df$flow != -1, ]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `for` loop solution

```
for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
    list1[[i]] <- list1[[i]][list1[[i]]$flow != -1,]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` with `subset`

```
out <- lapply(lst1, subset, subset = flow != -1)
```